# Detect value of child changed from false to true

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I detect if the value of the child i.e. `userStatus` is changed from `false` to `true` in [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data#child-events) database.

Below is the code that I trying to use, but it doesn't work. As, I understand, when the `userStatus` is changed from `false` to `true`, the below expression is no longer true and hence doesn't get triggered.

Can someone please suggest, how I could achieve this ?

```
usersRef.orderByChild("userStatus").equalTo(false).on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
  var userDetails   =   snapshot.val();
  var firstname     =   userDetails.firstName;
  console.log("userDetails, firstname: "+firstname);
});
```

**[EDIT]**

Below is my firebase db structure, where I am trying to trigger a `child_changed` event **only when** the `userStatus` changes from `false` to `true`.

[image: <code>Firebase db structure</code>]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Can you give an example of a write sequence (in code) that doesn't trigger the `child_changed`, but that you want to trigger?

Comment: I've added an edit to bring more clarity to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use a query that matches users with a `userStatus` of `false` and to then listen to the `child_removed` event. You will be notified when a user changes and no longer matches that query. That is, you will be notified when the `userStatus` changes from `false` to `true`.

```
usersRef.orderByChild("userStatus")
  .equalTo(false)
  .on("child_removed", function (snapshot) {
    var userDetails = snapshot.val();
    var firstname   = userDetails.firstName;
    console.log("userDetails (status changed to true), firstname: " + firstname);
  });
```